# How to write Http header for stream aac audio over TCP protocol

Tags: java, android, http, http-live-streaming, aac

I am trying to stream aac audio file from Android app to local host via Http TCP protocol.
I tried using this header:

```
 // will set header , will run only first time when start connection
void sendHeader() throws IOException {
    outputStreamWriter.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.write("Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=ahmed\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.write("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.write("Pragma: no-cache\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.write("Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.write("\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.flush();
}

   // using to display audio to browser
@Override
public Socket call() throws Exception {
    outputStreamWriter.write("--ahmed\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.write("Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.write("Content-Length: " + audiBytes.length + "\r\n");
    Log.e("len : ",String.valueOf(audiBytes.length ));
    outputStreamWriter.write("\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.flush();
    socket.getOutputStream().write(audiBytes);
    socket.getOutputStream().flush();
    outputStreamWriter.write("\r\n");
    outputStreamWriter.flush();
    return null;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I already used this header to stream images and it works perfectly.

Will appreciate your help
Many thanks

Comment: there must be more code to your client?

Comment: Are you encoding the audio with ADTS?

Comment: @Brad I'm encoding audio with acc

Comment: Right, but are you using ADTS as a wrapper for your AAC stream?